# DevOps Build and Pipeline Design Pattern - Need some advice on deploying many individual files

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines

We have a PoC on deploying a file to an old mainframe.  There are many types of deployments that we do but this question focuses on individual files.  We are able to SSH into the mainframe and we have a deployment pipeline with the steps needed to get one file into the correct location.

The problem is we have over 54,000 of these individual files.  During a release we may deploy as little as 1-5 files or large deployment may be 250 files.  Each of them will have a different source and target destination.  Some of them may be sources from the same folder and deployed to the same folder but that is not guaranteed.

We can make the assumption that the files are immutable.  There are issues on both build and release to consider:

Build - what is the artifact?  Do we use one artifact for each release that could contain 1-250 files?  We don't want to have 250 build scripts for a release, that we know.

Release - How do we use the pipelines.  If you batch them together then is it a one click deploy to that environment?  How would you determine if someone added a file to the release?  I guess we would need a new build that would create a new pipeline?

There are a few other things that come up like we need to check the status in our change management system to confirm that the ticket for that File is in a status that is approvable.  That is a deployment step currently.

Comment: Hi gperrego; can I ask, would it be practical to have the release always deploy all 54,000 files?

Comment: No, that wouldn't work.

Comment: I don't know if anyone is looking at  this but I'm leaning towards creating a branch of all files for each release and then creating an artifact on any changed files.

Comment: @gperrego - are the 54K files in the same branch, like master?

Comment: @StinkyTowel Yes, they are in the same branch.  We have an approach here that i'll document below.  I don't know if it really answers the question or just gives one approach to do this.

Comment: @gperrego - do you only deploy files that have changed?  Or deploy always?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the "answer" or not but this is our take on it so far:

**The Artifact**
We are going to create a "release" data file.  In this file there will be a list of files going with each deployment.  We will organize the files by product line and create a branch of all files for a specific product.  Then the build will read the files and create the artifact from the list of files related to that release. We will also include the data file in the artifact.

**Deployment**
We will create a Parent/Child release process.  The Parent script will loop through the data file and call the child script. The Child script will deploy an individual file which will be represented by a row in the data file.  To deploy to Production the Parent will be deployed only.  The child will not every be deployed individually.

**Multiple Deployment Times/Dependencies**
We have a requirement to Deploy certain files at certain times.  One production file deployment may be at 1 PM and another at 7 PM in the same release.  To accommodate this 
we will include deployment time in the data file.  After each file is deployed we will some how keep track that this file has been deployed.

**Change Management**
We will do our change management system check in each child script to make sure the file is ready to deploy.  If the individual file is not approved we will not stop processing, we will finish the deployment for any other files in the list that are approved and then as the last step in the deployment we will fail the deploy.  We need to make the "tracking" available to the teams to see what caused the deploy to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Making some assumptions here and is happy path, but perhaps this will help get you to the ultimate solution.

1. Have a **master** branch that has a **products** folder.  This folder would then have subfolders for each product, which has the files:

   *master/

    products/

      productA

      productB

      productN*
2. Dev Team would work on files in separate *fix* branches then merge into **master** via pull requests.  You can setup policies and gates for audit
3. Create a build pipeline with powershell script task that checks for deltas ([possible example](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/405854/view.html)) in **master** and copy/publish only those changes to an *artifact* destination folder with the same *product* subfolder layout
4. Create a release pipeline that has a stage for each product and/or destination path on the mainframe.  Each stage would have a custom task that copies the files from the appropriate product folder to the destination via SSH.  You could even create a task group that gets re-used then just use variables for folder paths, etc.  NOTE: The will be quite a few stages, but that's what release pipelines are for :)
5. Schedule the release pipeline to run at the desired times.  You can setup notifications on failures so someone or process can investigate/retry etc.